# JQuery , syncronized selection option

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, dom, frontend

I have to tag in my jsp with two identical select option.

I want that anytime I am chaining one , the second (that is in the bottom ) will change too.

```
<select class="groups">
    <option class='America' value='America'>America</option>
    <option class='Europe' value='Europe'>Europe</option>
    <option class='Asia' value='Asia'>Asia</option>
<select>

<select class="groups">
    <option class='America' value='America'>America</option>
    <option class='Europe' value='Europe'>Europe</option>
    <option class='Asia' value='Asia'>Asia</option>
<select>
```

So for instance anytime I am choosing Europe ( or any other ) I want all of my select get updated with the same value.

Comment: Sounds easy enough. When one changes, set the value of the other to its value.

Comment: `$('.groups').val($(this).val())`

Answer (score -2):

without jquery:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("groups").forEach(function(element){
  element.onchange = function(event) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("groups").forEach(function(x){
    x.value = event.target.value;
    });
  }
});
```

with jquery:

```
$('.groups').onchange = function(e){
  $('.groups').forEach(function(x){
  x.val(e.currentTarget().val)
  });
}
```

Comment: Please don't indulge help-vampires.

Comment: There are a several problems with your jQuery code.

Comment: There's no `event.value`. That should be `event.target.value`.